# Why am I getting WA for BUGLIFE on spoj

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hi i am doing this problem https://www.spoj.com/problems/BUGLIFE/ on SPOJ but i am getting WA, can anyone help. Here is my code.

I'm trying to use sets to solve this problem. I've heard about using Bipartite Graphs to solve this problem but I think using this approach should suffice unless there's some fault with my approach .  I've tried quite a few Testcases , but I don't know where my code is failing .

Additional Test cases for anyone who's willing to help :- 
 
http://spojtoolkit.com/history/BUGLIFE

Expected output for the test cases 
  :-
http://spojtoolkit.com/test/BUGLIFE

Sample Input :- 
2
3 3 
1 2 
2 3 
1 3 
4 2 
1 2 
3 4

Sample Output :- 
Scenario #1: 
Suspicious bugs found! 
Scenario #2: 
No suspicious bugs found!

My code's output is same as expected output .

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for(int s = 0 ; s < t ; s++ ){
        int bugs , inter; // Bugs and Interactions
        cin >> bugs >> inter;
        map<int,int> isDiscovered , male , female;
        int bug1 , bug2;
        vector<pair<int , int> > b; //stores pair of interactions
        for(int i = 0 ; i < inter ; i++){
            cin >> bug1 >> bug2;
            b.push_back(make_pair(bug1,bug2));
        }
        sort(b.begin() , b.end());

        bool ans = true;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < b.size() ; i++){
            bug1 = b[i].first;
            bug2 = b[i].second;
            //both not classified
            if(isDiscovered.find(bug1) == isDiscovered.end() && isDiscovered.find(bug2) == isDiscovered.end()){
                isDiscovered[bug1]++;
                isDiscovered[bug2]++;
                male[bug1]++;
                female[bug2]++;
            }
            //one classified
            if(isDiscovered.find(bug1) != isDiscovered.end() || isDiscovered.find(bug2) != isDiscovered.end()){
                if(isDiscovered.find(bug1) == isDiscovered.end()){
                    //bug1 does not exist
                    isDiscovered[bug1]++;
                    if(male.find(bug2) == male.end()){
                        //bug2 is female
                        male[bug1]++;
                    }
                    else{
                        //bug2 is male
                        female[bug1]++;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //bug2 does not exist
                    isDiscovered[bug2]++;
                    if(male.find(bug1) == male.end()){
                        //bug1 is female
                        male[bug2]++;
                    }else{
                        female[bug2]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            //both classified
            if(isDiscovered.find(bug1) != isDiscovered.end() && isDiscovered.find(bug2) != isDiscovered.end()){
                if(male.find(bug1) != male.end() && male.find(bug2) != male.end()){
                    //both males
                    ans = false;
                }
                else if(female.find(bug1) != female.end() && female.find(bug2) != female.end()){
                    //both females
                    ans = false;
                }
            }
            if(ans == false){
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << "Scenario #" << s+1 << ":" << endl;
        if(ans == false){
            cout << "Suspicious bugs found!" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "No suspicious bugs found!" << endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @john , I couldn't find an input on which my code fails ! I'm looking for an input on which my code fails .

Comment: It is part of problem solving to find an input that your code fails with

Comment: @KartikMadaan Sorry you've lost me, it sounds like you're complaining that your code is working.

Comment: @mtszkw , I've tried quite a few on Spoj Toolkit , but I couldn't find one !

Comment: @john , I actually don't have much knowledge about Bipartite graphs . I just think that it could be solved without using Bipartite Graphs . I don't know where my code fails ! And I'm pretty sure its a conceptual flaw rather than an implementation one .

Comment: Could you include additional test cases you've constructed to test your algorithm? Go for edge values (min bugs, max bugs, min size etc) and simple cases that exercise weird conditions.

Comment: @domen , I've added the link ( instead of copying all the test cases since the question is already quite lengthy )

Comment: Test cases *you've constructed* being the key words. These sort of challenges will normally have simple public test cases just for examples and to clarify description, but will not provide full elaborate test cases which confirm your code works on anything more complex.

Answer (score 0):

In case both bugs are new, you unconditionally say that the first one is a male, and the second one is female. It is not necessarily so. We only may assume that they are of different genders, but there is no grounds to assign the gender yet. Try

```
4 2
2 1
3 4
```

(same as case 2, with the second pair swapped).

Comment: I didn't get your test case . Did you mean 
   `<br>
    2 <br>
    3 3 <br>
    1 2 <br>
    2 3 <br>
    1 3 <br>
    4 2 <br>
    2 1 <br>
    3 4 <br>
    ?`
And , It doesn't matter whichever gender I put it in because I'm also sorting the queries so , it's either the first member of the query has already been discovered or if it hasn't , I'm arbitrarily putting it in first of the two sets . It'd be helpful if you could explain your test case !